# Using ProcessExit to shutdown hardware devices in c#?

Tags: c#, events, shutdown

I have a hardware ware device that needs to be unloaded at the end of program execution or it will be left in an undefined/unstable/dangerous state.  This is easy enough during normal operation, but during any sort of crash or unexpected circumstance, it usually doesn't get unloaded properly.

Searching, I found that I can setup an event to clean up the board on process exit, or at least a fraction of them:

```
public MainForm()
{
...
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit); 
...
}

static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            myHardwareDevice.checkAndPerformSafeShutdown();
}
```

where `checkAndPerformSafeShutdown` is a wrapper around native dll function call that cleans up the driver and puts all hardware in a safe state.  However, this fails to compile with:

> error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'projectNme.MainForm.myHardwareDevice'.

What is the scope of this event handler and why is it different then any other event handler in the class?  Is there someway I can get a reference to the hardware device?

Comment: Is `MyHardwareDevice` a class?

Comment: Have you declared `myHardwareDevice` as static?

Comment: also - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx?Redirected=true - doesn't answer your question, but may raise more

Answer (score 0):

Define the event handler as an instance method on your MainForm and you'll have access to all instance variables.

Comment: oh my god I can't believe I didn't notice the 'static'.  Close thread, delete my account :o